# LaTeX document language

Tags: languages

I am using LaTeX to write my scientific paper. My problem is, the paper is in a foreign language. So when I am making chapters, using

```
\chapter{...}
```

I get the default "Chapter 1, ..."

I want to set the entire document into French, so that it reads "Chapitre 1, ...". Same for "Table of contents", "Abstract", etc. I don't have a problem with the actual body of text, just those titles that pop up automatically.

Can anybody tell me the way, or should I re-download the program from some French source?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Just write `\documentclass{report}\usepackage[french]{babel}...`

Comment: I think an introduction to understand the basics will be a good investment before going on. Will take you about two days. http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/

Comment: Yes, thank you, I just started using LaTex today, all those tips and references will be very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

This will not only switch the predefined words to French, but also the hyphenation and some other things (e.g. spaces before and after punctuation marks).